# Python + open() + write on Windows - permission issue (IOError) for file created on OS X

Tags: python, file-io, ioerror

(I asked this previously, but have since accepted that it is not an issue with `openpyxl`, so changing tack)

Given an xlsx created on OS X, I open it for writing on that platform using `openpyxl` `load_workbook()`. I add some data, then I save it using `Workbook.save()` (to the same file).

All good on OS X, but when the program, and the XLSX, are transferred onto a Windows machine and executed, I get:

```
c:\Users\Me\Desktop\ROI>python roi_cut7.py > log.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "roi_cut7.py", line 379, in <module>
main()
File "roi_cut7.py", line 374, in main
processSource(wb, 'Taboola', taboolaSpends, taboolaRevenues)
File "roi_cut7.py", line 276, in processSource
wb.save(r'output.xlsx')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 298,
in save
save_workbook(self, filename)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 198, in sa
ve_workbook
writer.save(filename, as_template=as_template)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 180, in sa
ve
archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 756, in __init__
self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'output.xlsx'
```

Following extensive investigation, I've tried the following:

1. `chmod 777` on the XLSX before moving it to Windows icacls output.xlsx
2. Ruling out path issues by using `os.join` and `r''` raw notation
3. `icacls output.xlsx /grant everyone:F` on the file after moving it to Windows
4. Unticking the `read-only` checkbox under Attributes in the Windows folder Properties

... with no success. The Windows folder is a regular Windows folder. I can write to it both manually with new files, and programmatically. It's just the writing to this XLSX that is the issue.

I could update the script so that it reads from one file and writes to another (newly-created by openpyxl) file, but this workaround will only serve for a single day, since each subsequent day, the program needs to build upon the written file from the previous day, and if the file being *read* from is unchanged, this breaks down. Interestingly, I notice that if I open the XLSX in Excel, save it as a new file, update my program to read and write to this file new file, and re-execute, it works .... **but only once**. Every subsequent execution results in the IOError.

What would your next step be?

Comment: Can you create files in Windows using openpyxl? Are you running some kind of scheduler every day?

Comment: Does a regular Excel spreadsheet that has not be fiddled with by Python transfer from OS X to Windows (using the same mechanism) OK?  In other words, is this a Python issue or the different versions of Excel?

Comment: You save the file as 'seven.xlsx', but the error is about 'output.xlsx', how come?

Comment: @Rob Well-spotted. That's the corresponding error for when the input and output files are different (my unsuccessful attempt to get around the issue by reading from one but writing to another).

Comment: @CharlieClark Good suggestion - Yes just tried on the Windows machine `wb = openpyxl.Workbook()` followed by `wb.save('test.xlsx')` and it created the spreadsheet without problem.

Comment: Just a wild thing to look for: are there any temporary files left on either your Mac or on Windows?  I ask because your last paragraph implies that under some circumstances it fails on the second attempt.  If the spreadsheet is not being closed correctly and a recovery file  is left, that might screw things.  On Mac, these files are prefixed `~$`  on Windows they are usually in `C:\ Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Microsoft`

Comment: @cdarke Indeed I do see such a file on Mac, ~$output.xlsx in the cwd. Hmm, now looking for the equivalent of `Documents and Settings` on the Windows machine , which is 7 Enterprise.

Comment: This is definitely a permissions problem. It's possible in Windows, that if the file is open in Excel, that you can't open it from another process at the same time. Other operating systems are different. If you open the test file in openpyxl, can you also open it at the same time in Excel?

Comment: To illustrate that this is a permissions error: simply try `open("output.xlsx", "wb")` in the same folder (backup the file first!)

Comment: @CharlieClark Thanks to your persistence and curiosity, we have arrived at the cause. It was indeed down to the file being open in Excel at the time. I did not see an end in sight with this, and I don't think it would have dawned on me what was the true cause. Thanks again, particularly for sticking with this (and with my previous posts), long after it became clear it wasn't an openpyxl issue.

Comment: @CharlieClark The issue now goes away once I close Excel before trying to `wb.save`. But I notice now that on subsequent executions of my program, the issue reoccurs even after I kill any Python processes from the previous exection. I don't see any Excel processes in Task Manager - is there any other way the file open/saved could be left open after `wb.save` has been performed? Is there a process I need to kill?