# How to ensure a file is closed for writing in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, ioerror

The issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447975/python-open-write-on-windows-permission-issue-ioerror-for-file-created) looked initially like it was solvable by just having the spreadsheet closed in Excel before running the program.

It transpires, however, that having Excel closed is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition. The issue still occurs, but not on every Windows machine, and not every time (sometimes it occurs after a single execution, sometimes two).

I've modified the program such that it now reads from one spreadsheet and writes to a different one, still the issue presents itself.  I even go on to programmatically kill any lingering Python processes before running the program. Still no joy.

The `openpyxl` `save()` function instantiates `ZipFile` thus:

```
archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
```

... with `Zipfile` then using that to attempt to open the file in mode `'wb'` thus:

```
if isinstance(file, basestring):
    self._filePassed = 0
    self.filename = file
    modeDict = {'r' : 'rb', 'w': 'wb', 'a' : 'r+b'}
    try:
        self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
    except IOError:
        if mode == 'a':
            mode = key = 'w'
            self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
        else:
            raise
```

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows
>   makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
>   characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
>   is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data
>   is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that
>   in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading
>   and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to
>   the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary
>   files.

... which explains why mode 'wb' must be used.

Is there something in Python file opening that could possibly leave the file in some state of "openness"?

**Windows:** 8

**Python:** 2.7.10

**openpyxl:** latest

Comment: Not sure if I understand  your problem, but shouldn't you just `self.fp.close()` at the end of your operation?

Comment: It would be useful to record Windows, python and openpyxl versions when it works and when it doesn't. Have you thought of filling a bug-report?

Comment: @rroszkowiak  The code above is an extract from `ZipFile`, part of the Python standard library. I'd prefer not to touch it.

Comment: In Python, files need to be explicitly closed.  Don't rely on garbage collection to close the file for you, because garbage collection happens at unpredictable times - or not at all until the program exits.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson Better to use the `with` syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the problem is.  The Python close is immediate.  If Excel is invoked, it is far more likely that is the cause of any file sharing problems.  It is sloppy about closing the data file after reading it and intentionally creates a file lock file which persists for many seconds after it is no longer needed.  Can you narrow down what symptoms you are seeing?

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson Yes the last line in `openpyxl`'s `save` function does indeed close the file.

Comment: What is this the third or fourth question on the same issue? We can't see your code and we can't inspect your machine and without this I don't think the problem can be properly investigated.

Comment: @CharlieClark In the absence of any code, you yourself still managed to provide a tip in my previous question, one which helped me deal with the first manifestation of this issue. And now the other respondent's suggestions (and the answer below) are getting me much closer to solving this permanently. This is why I love Stack Overflow. Even in the absence of code, you guys are smart enough to think outside the box and creatively offer solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

First is to use `with` to close the file correctly.

```
with open("some.xls", "wb") as excel_file:
    #Do something
```

At the end of that the file will close on its own (see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)).

You can also make a copy of the file and work on the copied file.

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile

Comment: It's openpyxl code that does the file opening, so I'd rather leave that alone. Your suggestion to copy the file is an excellent one though, and I will certainly trial it.